# Autfac injecting service that has parameter in constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I understand how to inject a nullable parameter into a constructor using **TypedParameter** in the [autofac docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html#available-parameter-types).  I am struggling to understand how to then inject that service into another service, where the parameter will come from.  Here is some example code:

```
// interface
pubic Interface IProvider 
{
    string GetParameter();
}

// implementation
public class Provider : IProvider
{
    private readonly int? _parameterId;
    public Provider(int? parameterId){
        _parameterId = parameterId;
    }
    public string GetParameter(){
         // go get my parameter from wherever using int that was passed to constructor
    }
}
```

Now in my api controller i might inject this service so i can get a parameter:

```
public class ParameterController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IProvider _provider;
    public ParameterController(IProvider provider){
         _provider = provider;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetParameterNoInput(){
         _provider.GetParameter(null);
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetParameter(int input){
        // my provider wants this input but not as a passed parameter
        // I don't know how to do this
    }
 }
```

And of course the registration

```
builder.RegisterType<Provider>().As<IProvider>().InstancePerRequest()
   .WithParameter(new TypedParameter(typeof(Guid?), "parameterId"));
```

FWIW, I am aware this isn't a great design choice but it is what is being dictated to me.  What is the pattern for dealing with this in autofac?  To clarify, the part that is being dictated is that IProvider has the nullable int parameterId injected to it rather than having exposed methods that accept the the int

Should i be doing something like this in my controller:

```
Func<int?>, IProvider _newProvider;
public ParameterController(Func<int?, IProvider> provider){
    _newProvider = provider;
}

// and then in my api i can do
[HttpGet]
public string GetParameter(int input){
    var provider = _newProvider(input);
    provider.GetParameter();
}
```

Comment: You stated this is whats being dictated to you, do you have any "wiggle room" per se? If all instances of Provider need the same value, you could use the IOptions interface and then configure the option on startup.

Comment: @TylerHundley unfortunately not.  I think i need to use a delegate factory here, updating the question

Answer (score 1):

Autofac allows you to pass a parameter when you register your service. In your case, that would look something like this

```
builder.Register(c => new Provider(someInt)).As<IProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Assuming all instances of Provider need the same parameter passed in.

More information and a couple other methods of configuring this can be found in the [Autofac Docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html)

Comment: the value for someInt is a runtime value and changes so i'm not sure this works, i do believe the **Func<int?, IProvider>** approach is going to work though and allows me to create multiple instances of the provider in the same method